# Problem at sending a javascript object list to controller in Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I'm trying to retrieve a list of javascript objects in Java Spring MVC but when it arrives to the controller is empty.

I've been reading a lot about but I don't know how it works

This is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
                    url : 'ajax/abrir_cotizacion',
                    data : {
                        listaunidades: [{
                                idtipounidad: 1, 
                                modelo: 2013, 
                                cantidad: 1, 
                                tipopago: 1,
                                costounidad: 1500000,
                                ivaoperacion: 25000,
                                totaloperacion: 1504000,
                                enganche: 750000,
                                idplazo: 3
                            },
                            {
                                idtipounidad: 2, 
                                modelo: 2012, 
                                cantidad: 2, 
                                tipopago: 2,
                                costounidad: 1500000,
                                ivaoperacion: 25000,
                                totaloperacion: 1504000,
                                enganche: 750000,
                                idplazo: 6
                            }]
                    },
                    type : 'POST',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    success : function(data) {

                    },
                    error : function(xhr, status) {
                        alert('Disculpe, existió un problema');
                    },
                    complete : function(xhr, status) {
                        //alert('Petición realizada');
                    }
                });
```

And below my controller and model required to this.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax/abrir_cotizacion", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object abrircotizacion(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute ArrayList<Unidades> listaunidades) {
    try {
        Injector inj = AppInjector.getInjector();
        return new MsgPojo(1, "Se abre la cotización");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LoggerUtils.printLog(this.getClass(), Level.SEVERE, ex, null, Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace());
        return new MsgPojo(-1, "Ocurrio un error al cargar los datos. " + ex.toString());
    }
}


public class Unidad {

    private int idtipounidad;
    private int modelo;
    private int cantidad;
    private int tipopago;
    private double costounidad;
    private double ivaoperacion;
    private double totaloperacion;
    private double enganche;
    private int idplazo;

   //getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm using Spring Boot 2.1.4
and i have tried this and it is working.

**HomeController.class**

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public void test(@RequestBody UserDTO[] userDTO) {
        logger.info(userDTO.length + ""); //expect 2
    }

}
```

**UserDTO.class**

```
@Data
public class UserDTO {

    private String email;
    private String nickname;

}
```

and i'm using **postman**.

```
POST /test? HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
[
    {
        "email": "test@test.co.kr",
        "nickname": "test1"
    },
    {
        "email": "test2@test.co.kr",
        "nickname": "test2"
    }
]
```

and **output:**

```
2019-05-24 11:04:40.871  INFO 1860 --- [p-nio-80-exec-5] k.c.k.w.w.s.controller.HomeController    : 2
```

also i debugged to check my userDTO.
the email and nickname was set to the parameters i sent in postman.

changing parameter like this:

```
[
  {
    "idtipounidad": 1,
    "modelo": 2013,
    "cantidad": 1,
    "tipopago": 1,
    "costounidad": 1500000,
    "ivaoperacion": 25000,
    "totaloperacion": 1504000,
    "enganche": 750000,
    "idplazo": 3
  },
  {
    "idtipounidad": 2,
    "modelo": 2012,
    "cantidad": 2,
    "tipopago": 2,
    "costounidad": 1500000,
    "ivaoperacion": 25000,
    "totaloperacion": 1504000,
    "enganche": 750000,
    "idplazo": 6
  }
]
```

and your controller:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax/abrir_cotizacion", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object abrircotizacion(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody Unidad[] unidad) {
   ....
}
```

i hope this work.. 
And try postman. This is quite useful.